# Solving a integral with absolute value

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I don't know how to solve the following integral:

$$ \frac{2\pi}R\int_{r_1}^{r_2}r(r+R-|r-R|)dr $$

I have solved it when $R \le r_1$ and $R \ge r_2$ but I need the answer for $ r_1\lt R \lt r_2$. 
R is a constant as well as $r_1$ and $r_2$.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Split the integral at $R$, $\int_{r_1}^{r_2} = \int_{r_1}^R + \int_R^{r_2}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $r_1 < R < r_2$, then

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{r_1}^{r_2}r(r+R-|r-R|)dr
&=& \int_{r_1}^{R}r(r+R+(r-R))dr + \int_{R}^{r_2}r(r+R-(r-R))dr\\
&=& \int_{r_1}^{R}2r^2dr + \int_{R}^{r_2}2rR\,dr
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

A good thing to notice is $$r+R-|r-R|=2\min(r,R)$$.